# Is there a way to pass a synthetic event through addEventListener?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I have to pass a reference of a button to it's children like this:

```
function Parent() {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <Child button={ref} />
      <button ref={ref}>Do something</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

then in the child component I am adding an event listener like this

```
function Child({ button }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    button.current.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
    return ()=>button.current.removeEventListener("click", someFunction);
  }, []);
  ....
}
```

`someFunction` is a function that I am using from a third party library(react-hook-form) which calls `e.persist()`

```
function someFunction(e){
 e.persist();
 ....
}
```

because I am passing it from the `addEventListener` a normal event is being passed instead of a synthetic one so I am getting an error that `e.persist` is not a function, how can I solve this or what is a better approach to this?
Note that the button has to be where it is, I can't create it inside that Child component itself because on different screens it has different functions, and `<Child/>` is just one of the screens, I am switching between them based on a condition

Comment: You can pass `onClick` prop to `Child` if it's not against some requirement..

Comment: the problem is within the <Child/> itself some data change so I have to pass that data

Comment: No problem. You can pass the data along the `onClick`. Where `someFunction` defined anyway? Maybe it's better to create a codesandbox with a real demo.

Comment: `someFunction` is a function returned from a third part library (react-hook-form) and it is created inside that  `<Child/>` components because it is used for validation inside the inputs that are inside the `<Child/>` component, what do you mean pass the onClick? one that accepts a callback?

Comment: Now I understand the situation. Well.. good question :)

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler solution, but this is what comes to my mind. Basically, it takes the Pubsub pattern into React context. Take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bird-9notp?file=/src/App.js. If you need explanations, let me know. If you like it, I can put it as answer.

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks man, but I followed a different approach without using that third party library